# Natural map $\newcommand{\Ell}{\operatorname{\mathcal{ELL}}} \Ell(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}) \to \Ell(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

An elliptic curve $E$ over $\Bbb{C}$ is *defined over a subfield $⊆ℂ$* if there exists an elliptic curve $E_0$ given by a Weierstrass equation with coefficients in $$ such that $\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}} E\cong E_0×_{\Spec(K)}{\Spec{\Bbb{C}}}$ as curves over $\Bbb{C}$.

Let $\newcommand{\Ell}{\operatorname{\mathcal{ELL}}} \Ell(\overline{\Bbb{Q}})$ be the quotient set
$$
\frac{\{\text{elliptic curves over $\Bbb{C}$ which are defined over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$}\}}{(\text{isomorphisms over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$})}.
$$
Let $\Ell( \Bbb{C})$ be the quotient set
$$
\frac{\{\text{elliptic curves over $\Bbb{C}$ which are defined over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$}\}}{(\text{isomorphisms over $\Bbb{C}$})}.
$$

Then, what is an natural map from $\Ell(\overline{\Bbb{Q}})$ to $\Ell( \Bbb{C})$ ?
I think I need to use some kind of universal property of fiber product.

Comment: No, this is just abbriviation of 'elliptic', this is notation in Silverman's 'advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'.

Comment: OK, but the first set doesn't make sense. If $E$ is an elliptic curve that isn't defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, then I don't know what an isomorphism over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is.

Comment: Thank you, I edited.

Comment: If we choose an embedding $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, then a $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-isomorphism is also a $\mathbb{C}$-isomorphism. So we can simply map the $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-isomorphism class of an elliptic curve $E$ to its $\mathbb{C}$-isomorphism class.

Comment: Next, this is not your question but putting the curves in $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ form you can get farily explicit descriptions of your sets.

Comment: This all becomes a great deal less mysterious once you realise that the set $ELL(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is canonically in bijection with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ itself, via the j-invariant map (see Silverman "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" Prop III.1.4). Similarly $ELL({\mathbb{C}})$ is $\mathbb{C}$, and the natural map $ELL(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}) \to ELL(\mathbb{C})$ is just the inclusion $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \into \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

From the commments: If we choose an embedding $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \iota: \overline{\Q} \hookrightarrow \C$, then every $\overline{\Q}$-isomorphism is also a $\C$-isomorphism. So we can simply map the $\overline{\Q}$-isomorphism class of an elliptic curve $E$ to its $\C$-isomorphism class.

This can be made concrete by noting that, over an algebraically closed field $L$, the isomorphism class of an elliptic curve is completely determined by its $j$-invariant, and every $j$-invariant occurs. (See Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Proposition III.1.4(b) and (c), p. 45.) In other words the $j$-invariant map
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\Ell}{\operatorname{\mathcal{ELL}}}
\Ell(L) &\overset{\sim}{\to} L\\
E &\mapsto j(E)
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism, and we have the following commutative diagram.
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Ell(\overline{\Q}) @>{}>> \Ell(\C);\\
@V{j}V{}V @VV{j}V \\
\overline{\Q} @>>{\iota}> \C
\end{CD}
$$